# default array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to assign a default values to arrays in javascript?

ex: `an array with 24 slots that defaults to 0`

Comment: check out [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.repeat= function(what, L){
 while(L) this[--L]= what;
 return this;
}
```

**var A= [].repeat(0, 24);**

alert(A)

Comment: What's with the weird (Javascript-wise) naming conventions? (@ the use of capital letters.)

Comment: Suppose I want to do this but with an array of objects, how do I do that? var A = [].repeat(new myObject(), 10) just copies the references and do not instantiate a new object every time

Comment: @Morten `repeat = function(what, count, isFactory) { ... }; [].repeat(function() { return new myObject(); }, 10, true);`

Comment: This is late, but I just want to add to anyone reading this in the future: **do not call it `repeat`** as ES6 _will_ implement a `repeat` method, meaning you will overwrite default behaviour, which is discouraged. Good solution though.

Comment: The answer below by deadrunk is better, it doesn't change the array prototype, but does the same thing.

Answer (score 107):

You can use the `fill` function on an array:

```
Array(24).fill(0)
```

*Note:* `fill` was only introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (alias "6"), so as of 2017 browser support is still very limited (for example no Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 53):

```
var a = Array.apply(null, Array(24)).map(function() { return 0 });

// or:
var a = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(Boolean).map(Number);
```

Comment: How is map allowed on the first Array? Something about the way you construct the Array allows map to work, when it normally would not

Answer (score 24):

the best and easiest solution is :

```
Array(length of the array).fill(a default value you want to put in the array)
```

example

```
Array(5).fill(1)
```

and result will be

```
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

you can put any thing you like in it:

```
Array(5).fill({name : ""})
```

Now if you want to change some of the current value in the array
you can use

```
[the created array ].fill(a new value , start position, end position(not included) )
```

like

```
[1,1,1,1,1].fill("a",1,3)
```

and output is

```
[1, "a", "a", 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 20):

A little wordy, but it works.

```
var aray = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
```

Comment: @KnickerKicker - no, for a one-off 24 element array, I'd probably do exactly this.  If it were a large number of items or I needed it repeatedly, then I'd be more clever about it.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't answer the question "Is there a way to assign a default values to arrays in javascript?" What this answer does address is the clarifying example.

Comment: by far the most efficient and clean way to create an array with 24 zeros.

Answer (score 15):

If you use a "very modern" browser (check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility)), you can rely on `fill`:

```
var array = new Array(LENGTH);
array.fill(DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

For several reasons, the use of `new Array()` is not appreciated by a lot of developers; so you can do the same as follows:

```
var array = [];
for(var i=0; i<LENGTH; ++i) array.push(DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

The latter is much more compatible, and as you can see both solutions are represented by two lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ES6 and up you can use

```
new Array(24).fill(0);
```

this also works:

```
Array.from({ length: 24}, () => 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

You have to use a loop.

```
var a = new Array(24);
for (var i = a.length-1; i >= 0; -- i) a[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Technically it's still a loop, moved into a function.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use:

```
function replicate (n, x) {
  var xs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    xs.push (x);
  }
  return xs;
}
```

---

Example:

```
var hellos = replicate (100, "hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

And now, more cleverly :)
@see [JavaScript Array reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) 
[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomasjurman/7qyqr/)

```
var len = 100;
var ch = '0';
alert ( new Array(len).join( ch ) );
```

Comment: Here's a version that gives you numbers as requested in the question: `Array(24).join().split('').map(function(){return 0})`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Lodash` (https://lodash.com/docs), a robust library for array manipulation which is available for browser too.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var A = _.fill(Array(24), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest one:

```
myArray = new Array(24).fill(0)
```

Comment: [Your answer is redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347075/497418).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the same -

`Array.from(Array(24),()=>5)`

`Array.from` accepts a second param as its map function.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].fill.call({ length: 24 }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax which i am using below is based on ECMA Script 6/es6

let arr=[];

arr.length=5; //Size of your array;

[...arr].map(**Boolean**).map(**Number**); //three dot operator is called **spread Operator** introduce in ECMA Script 6

------------Another way-------------

**let variable_name=new Array(size).fill(initial_value)**

for ex- let arr=new Array(5).fill(0) **//fill method is also introduced in es6**

> Another way as per **ECMA 5 or es5**

**var variable_name=Array.apply(null,Array(size)).map(Boolean).map(Number)**

var arr=Array.apply(null,Array(5)).map(Boolean).map(Number);

All of them will give you same result :
**[0,0,0,0,0]**

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1-D array
// array with length 3 and defaults to null
Array(3).fill(null);
/*
  This will look like
  [null, null, null]
*/

// for, 2-D array
// array with length 3 and default value an array of length 3
Array(3)
  .fill(null)
  .map(() => Array(3).fill(null));

/*
This will look like
[[null, null, null],
[null, null, null],
[null, null, null]]

*/
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i will add the explanation and will make sure to always add the explanation whenever i answer.

Comment: thanks @Abhishek, it's just a recommendation that will improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score -3):

```
(new Array(5).toString().replace(/,/g, "0,") + "0").split(",")

// ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
```

Comment: I have no idea why this was ever upvoted. He asked for an array full of 0s not the string version of 0. plus this code is horribly written, why use a regex replace when you can just do `var a = new Array(6).join(0).split('')`?

Answer (score -6):

If you want BigO(1) instead of BigO(n) please check below solution:

Default value of an array is `undefined`. So if you want to set default to 0, you have to loop all elements of array to set them to 0.

If you have to do that, it's ok. But I think it'll better if you check the value when want to get value of the element.

Define a function 'get': to get value of the array. myArray[index], if myArray[index] undefined, return '0', else return the value.

```
const get = (arr, index) => {
  return arr[index] === undefined ? 0 : arr[index];
}
```

Use:

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 1, 4];
get(myArray, 2); // --> 'b' 
get(myArray, 102344); // --> 0;
```

Comment: `function get (i) { return 0; }`

Comment: Big-O of my solution is O(1)
Another ways alway have O(n)