# javascript create empty array of a given size

Tags: javascript

in javascript how would I create an empty array of a given size

Psuedo code:

```
X = 3;
createarray(myarray, X, "");
```

output:

```
   myarray = ["","",""]
```

Comment: You'd probably use [*Array.prototype.fill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044760/default-array-values)

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4852017/465053).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

```
var arr = new Array(5);
console.log(arr.length) // 5
```

Comment: The OP asked `in javascript how would I create an empty array of a given size`. This solves that problem.

Comment: The OP has provided an example of "empty".

Comment: Well this is another option to the question. They can choose any of the answers provided, that's the glory of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 375):

**1)** To create new array which, you **cannot iterate over**, you can use array constructor:

`Array(100)` or `new Array(100)`

**2)** You can create new array, which **can be iterated over** like below:

**a)** All JavaScript versions

- Array.apply:
  `Array.apply(null, Array(100))`

**b)** From ES6 JavaScript version

- Destructuring operator:
  `[...Array(100)]`
- Array.prototype.fill
  `Array(100).fill(undefined)`
- Array.from
  `Array.from({ length: 100 })`

You can map over these arrays like below.

- `Array(4).fill(null).map((u, i) => i)` *[0, 1, 2, 3]*
- `[...Array(4)].map((u, i) => i)` *[0, 1, 2, 3]*
- `Array.apply(null, Array(4)).map((u, i) => i)` *[0, 1, 2, 3]*
- `Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((u, i) => i)` *[0, 1, 2, 3]*

Comment: Array.prototype.fill (>=ES6) https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array.prototype_methods_Array.prototype.fill_a_href=_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill_title=_MDN_documentation_img_src=_../mdn.png_alt=_MDN_(Mozilla_Development_Network)_logo_width=_15_height=_13_/_/a_nbsp;

Comment: Enlightenment of the day - when you mention in part (A) that a newly created array using constructor syntax is not even iteratable. Javascript really surprises at times.

Comment: What is the size of `Array(10000)` with `empty x 10000`?

Comment: Its length is 10000, you can check it by `console.log(Array(10000).length)` But if you run `Array(10000).forEach((u, i) => console.log(i))`, you will get no output

Comment: `Array.apply('x', Array(10))` is actually `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: Someone please explain 1). Why can't you iterate?

Comment: Also `Array.from({ length:4 }, (u, i) => i)`

Answer (score 62):

We use `Array.from({length: 500})` since 2017.

Comment: @gion_13: I see it being voted up and [mine](/a/48016225/6314667) being voted down. Reason?

Comment: @7vujy0f0hy I don’t know why you got down votes. I gave you an up vote, although your solution is a bit less intuitive than this one.

Comment: @gion_13: Thanks for confirming there’s nothing wrong with my solution ☺.

Answer (score 35):

***As of ES5 (when this answer was given):***

If you want an empty array of `undefined` elements, you could simply do

```
var whatever = new Array(5);
```

this would give you

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

In newer versions, this now gives

```
[empty × 5]
```

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936008/difference-between-empty-and-undefined-in-javascript) on the difference between empty and undefined.

If you wanted it to be filled with empty strings, you could do

```
whatever.fill('');
```

which would give you

```
["", "", "", "", ""]
```

And if you want to do it in one line:

```
var whatever = Array(5).fill('');
```

Comment: new Array(2) doesn't give you [undefined, undefined]. It gives you an array that isn't iterable.

Comment: OK. There's something else going on I don't understand. I'm creating a new array with `new Array(2)` and what I get back is `[ <2 empty items> ]` not `[undefined, undefined]`. Using `.map` on the former has no effect. However, I can iterate over it using a `for...of` loop. If I create a new array using literal notation `a = [undefined, undefined]` then I can use `.map` on it.

Comment: @JCF for...of uses iterator protocol, so it behaves differently than forEach/map. Iterators loose emptiness information

Comment: @TomaszBłachut @JCF For the down-voters, please keep in mind that this answer was given over 4 years ago – at which time, this answer was 100% valid. ES6 and ES7 did not start rolling out to browsers until mid-2016 and mid-2018, respectively. At the time of this answer, the JS version would have been ES5. If you need further proof that this _is_ the way ES5 worked, simply spin up an older instance of Chrome – at the time of this answer, it would have been v48 – and run `Array(5)`. You will see the following output: `[undefined x 5]`.

Comment: @jeffdill2 It's best to add new information to the answer itself. The comments are not always fully read.

Answer (score 22):

Try using `while` loop, `Array.prototype.push()`

```
var myArray = [], X = 3;
while (myArray.length < X) {
  myArray.push("")
}
```

Alternatively, using `Array.prototype.fill()`

```
var myArray = Array(3).fill("");
```

Comment: `.fill()` is an elegant one liner solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

In 2018 and thenceforth we shall use `[...Array(500)]` to that end.

Comment: into the future!

Comment: Hilariously this (and similar) is 50% slower than just ``(() => { let n = []; for(var i=0;i<500;i++){y.push("");} return n; })()``.

Comment: That reeks of premature optimization, maybe if you're intending to create a bunch of arrays with tens of millions of elements you might want to consider it but a few nanoseconds, for most cases, isn't going to make it worth the readability hit.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create anonymous array with some values so you can use this syntax.

```js
var arr = new Array(50).fill().map((d,i)=>++i)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both javascript methods repeat() and split() together.

```js
" ".repeat(10).split(" ")
```

This code will create an array that has 10 item and each item is empty string.

```js
const items = " ".repeat(10).split(" ")

document.getElementById("context").innerHTML = items.map((item, index) => index)

console.log("items: ", items)
```

```html
<pre id="context">

</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created benchmark tests for generating the empty arrays for iteration. The spread operator is the fastest. Array.from({length:n}) is the slowest.

- Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map()
- [...Array(n)].map()
- Array(n).fill(null).map()
- Array.from({ length: n }).map()
- Array.from({ length:n }, (item, i) => i)

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/25596/1/compare-the-ways-to-generate-an-empty-array-for-iterati
[image]