# AEM HTL looping using data-sly-repeat

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

```
<footer id="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row double">
                        <div class="6u">
                            <div class="row collapse-at-2">
                                <div data-sly-repeat="${properties.colNum}" data-sly-unwrap>
                                <div class="6u">
                                    <h3>Accumsan</h3>
                                    <ul class="alt">
                                        <li><a href="#">Nascetur nunc varius</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Vis faucibus sed tempor</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Massa amet lobortis vel</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Nascetur nunc varius</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="6u">
                            <h2>Aliquam Interdum</h2>
                            <p>Blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan. Justo aliquet massa adipiscing cubilia eu accumsan id. Arcu accumsan faucibus vis ultricies adipiscing ornare ut. Mi accumsan justo aliquet.</p>
                            <ul class="icons">
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-linkedin"><span class="label">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-pinterest"><span class="label">Pinterest</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; Untitled. All rights reserved.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

I am trying to use data-sly-repeat to loop and I have verified that the value of colNum is 2 but still the loop is running only once. In other words, it doesn't loop through irrespective of the value. I also hardcoded the value 3 but it still won't run the loop more than once. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood how `data-sly-repeat` is intended to be used. You can read [their documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/block-statements.html#repeat) to get clarification.

Two things:

1. `data-sly-repeat` repeats the whole element that is marked, while `data-sly-list` only repeats the content of the element. In your case it seems `list` is more appropriate.. You can eliminate the actual `div` that you are currently unwrapping.
2. Rather than passing in a **number** of times to repeat the HTML you pass in a **list** of things to iterate over. The html is rendered for each item in the list, with the `${item}` variable being used to hold the current item.

So, you'll have to write some Java of JS code to turn your `colNum` into a list of that size.

For example, using the [JS Use API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/use-api/javascript.html). (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937349/javascript-create-empty-array-of-a-given-size) for ways to create empty iterable arrays)

```
"use strict";
use(function () {
    let n = properties.get("colNum", 0);
    return {
        columns: [...Array(100)] // empty, iterable, array of size n
    };
});
```

And calling it from the HTL. Notice I removed the extraneous `div` and am using `data-sly-list` to loop over the `n` length array of empty elements

```
<div class="row collapse-at-2"
     data-sly-use.config="<JS-file-name>"
     data-sly-list="${config.columns}">
    <div class="6u">
        <h3>Accumsan</h3>
        <ul class="alt">
            <li><a href="#">Nascetur nunc varius</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vis faucibus sed tempor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Massa amet lobortis vel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nascetur nunc varius</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In sightly you can only iterate over a collection using sly-repeat or sly-list.So instead here instead using the ColNum directly you will have to make a simple collection .
Refer: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/block-statements.html

Answer (score 0):

`data-sly-repeat` needs an iterable object. You can provide a dummy array with the needed number of elements or, even better, an array with usefull things, such as column names or data.