# Issue with multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional array in javascript.

The following code generates the following error: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference

```js
var data = [["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"]];

data[1][0] = "test";
```

I assume that I need to somehow "pre-allocate" the array so it knows that it is multi-dimensional.

I will be filling this array in one row at a time in a for loop if that makes anything simpler.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can only access `data[0]` which equals `["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"]`. To add an item to `data` use `data.push(<something>)`.

Comment: `data[1]` doesn't exist on your example, only `data[0]`

Comment: `data[1]` is not defined, try `data[0][0]`

Comment: Multidimensional arrays aren't really a thing in JS (JS *arrays* aren't actually arrays at all). You can have arrays within arrays though, but all of the 'sub-arrays' are completely separate from each other, so yes, you have to create every sub-array individually.

Comment: Adding `data[1] = []` before `data[1][0] = "test"` should sort it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your log indicates, `data[1]` is `undefined`.

There are a number of ways to define the values of `data[0–99]` as empty arrays. In es6 for instance, `Array(100).fill([])`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246860/1664393.

Answer (score 1):

This code will fix your problem `data[1] = []` it creates a new array at this position.

```js
var data = [["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"]];
data[1] = [];
data[1].push("test")
console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // [["Timestamp","kWh Produced","kWh Used"],["test"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "data" is an array with a single element (an array of three strings), so `data[1]` is undefined.

```
var data = [["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"]];
// data[1] // => undefined
```

You simply need to append (or assign) new values to the data array to make use of them.

```
data.push([]); // or data[1] = []
data[1]; // => []
data[1][0] = "test";
data[1]; // => ["test"]
data[1].push("foo");
data[1]; // => ["test", "foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

- In JS as others programming languages, the array's indexes are zero-based.
- You're trying to get a value from index `1`, however that index is equals than the current array `length = 1`.

---

```
  0 <--- Position 
  |
  v                
[ ["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"] ]
                                            ^
                                            |
                                            +---- Length = 1
```

So, `data[1]` is invalid because is beyond the array's boundaries.

You need to get the first position: `data[0][0]` and replace it with the new value.

```js
var data = [["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"]];

data[0][0] = "test";
console.log(data);
```

If you want to add a new value, you need to get the first position: `data[0]` and push the new value.

```js
var data = [["Timestamp", "kWh Produced", "kWh Used"]];

data[0].push("test");
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone.

Adding `data[1] = []` before the `data[1][0] = "test"`, as suggested by Andrew Boone, did the trick.