Javascript: Array(3).map() vs [...Array(3)].map() behavior makes no sense
In Chrome Version 125.0.6422.76 (Official Build) (64-bit), I'm seeing this weird behavior with the Array constructor:

Notice that a's length is correctly stored as 3 internally.
I care less if Javascript is doing an internal optimization by lazily allocating the 3 (or more) elements later (say, during element assignment) as long as an array of length 3 is returned as an object for the map call in a.map().
Apparently, it isn't, since no foo's get printed as they do with b.map().

you cannot iterate when created using Array constructor https://stackoverflow.com/a/41246860

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays empty slots are skipped during iteration

.map() skips over empty element, and spread syntax replace the empty element with undefined

Read about sparse arrays

Thanks, sparse arrays and definitions of map vs join etc is the real answer. Thanks, to all those who took the time to respond.

When you initialize an array using Array constructor, it's an empty array. Yes, it has an length, which means JS stored a block of memory for the future use cases but it is completely empty. So, there is nothing to iterate over.
In the your second case, b array, there is an array with undefined elements. So, you can iterate over it.
