# Initialize Array with default value

Tags: javascript

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19286846) and I've stumbled upon the need of Array.apply to fill array:

```
var array = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function() { return 0; });
```

I've checked and this won't actually work:

```
var array = Array(5).map(function() { return 0; });
```

I know i could do

```
var array = Array(5).fill(0);
```

to obtain same result as the first method, I'm just wondering why it needs Array.apply with null as parameter.

Comment: What do you understand `var array = Array(5)` to do?

Comment: You can also use `Array.from()` instead of `Array()` and `.map()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
have two Parameters

**thisArg**

> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not
>   be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in
>   non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the
>   global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

**argsArray**

> An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which fun should
>   be called, or null or undefined if no arguments should be provided to
>   the function.

For details [visit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: I think (at least, I thought) what apply does, I just can't figure out what it does in this context. Boxing Array(5) (that is just an empty array of length 5) transforms it in 5 'undefined' parameters, right?