# Fill Array empty

Tags: javascript

I want to fill an not completed array. I will show an example:

```js
var main = [
{ "id":"0", "value":500 },
{ "id":"3", "value":300 }
]

var fill = []


for (i = 0 ; i < main.length; i++){
    fill[main[i].id] = main[i].value
}

console.log(fill)
```

How do i fill these empty arrays with `0` ?

**Thanks!**

Comment: `fill[main[i].id] = 0` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044760/default-array-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont know how long the array is, i would do it like this

```
 var main = [
{ "id":"0", "value":500 },
{ "id":"3", "value":300 }
]

var fill = []
for (var i = 0 ; i < main.length; i++){
    fill[main[i].id] = main[i].value
}
for (var j = 0 ; j < fill.length; j++){
    if(fill[j] === undefined){
        fill[j] = 0
    }
}
console.log(fill)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with a pre-filled array:

```js
var main = [
{ "id":"0", "value":500 },
{ "id":"3", "value":300 }
]

var fill = new Array(4).fill(0);


for (i = 0 ; i < main.length; i++){
    fill[main[i].id] = main[i].value
}

console.log(fill)
```

Comment: Thats works well man, but this "id" comes to me dynamically, there is a way to fill the final `fill` var with zero's?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution that works even if you don't know the max size of the array you will fill, you can try adding this at the end:

```
fill.map(function (el) {
  return el === undefined ? 0 : el; 
});
```

Or in a ES6+ environment:

```
fill.map(el => el === undefined ? 0 : el);
```